Minerals in asteroids that can only be detected indirectly
A small team of astronauts are sent to setup a mining operation on an asteroid. They are specifically equipped for mining and refining one very specific mineral.
This mineral is common, ~99% of asteroids in this area have significant deposits. It could be rare on earth. There are some that don't have any though, and the mining company wants to be super sure. The mining vessel is equipped with sensors that, when it gets closer to a cluster of asteroids, it can do some sort of scan to find an asteroid guaranteed to have the mineral they are looking for.
"Area" here means, for example, the Trojans. A group relatively close together at least compared to how long the journey is anyways and mostly similar mineral composition.
This scan should have almost no false positive rate but a very high false negative rate. As in, even if the scan does not detect the mineral it's most likely still there. I'm looking for a combination of scanning technique and mineral and asteroid secondary properties that allows for such a high false negative rate.
I was thinking maybe some asteroids contain some secondary chemical which reacts with the mineral and creates something detectable. Eg. They can't detect Cadmium directly but can somehow detect Cadmium Oxide, however most asteroids don't have any oxygen to form the oxide. I don't know what kind of scan technique could detect the oxide but not the base metal though.
Plot Background
The navigator for the mining ship has been completely ignoring the scan results and is setting course for specific asteroids for personal reasons. This has always worked out so far because even if the scanners are negative most asteroids contain plenty of the resource they are looking for. The conspiracy is revealed when they set up on one asteroid that doesn't have any.
My question
What combination of minerals and scan technique could allow for such a high false negative rate?
Clarification/Answers to Comments

Why even bother scanning if 99% of the asteroids have this mineral?

The spaceship has come a very long way, and it has only enough equipment to mine on a single asteroid. If there is no mineral there the equipment is consumed and can't be re-used. Even though the risk is small the cost would be enormous if the entire trip is wasted.

The guy in charge is more like finding a false-positive even, because he assumes it is there, but it isn't. Shouldn't he be more like surprised that it is there, although he thought it wouldn't?

Most of the asteroids have the mineral, even if the scans return negative. So it's no surprise if, when not ignoring the scan, they still find the mineral. The conspirator took a calculated risk that didn't pan out.

Surely "real" miners would consider 99% as 100 and just go to the nearest asteroid?

First of, the 99% metric isn't important. Maybe the Navigator things a risk of up to 85% is accepted but the company thinks a risk of up to 95% is acceptable. In that case with a 90% risk the story would make sense?
Secondly, at the distance where the scanning takes place, they can go to any asteroid with almost equal difficulty.

How does it make sense that most asteroids have some mineral but the other one has not just little but none?

The group of asteroids that have the mineral could all come from a single source (eg. a proto-planet that blew up. Orbital mechanics also has a tendency to sort asteroids roughly by material (eg. inner planets are more iron rich).
The asteroids that has none could come from a different orbit but have been knocked out of course somehow and is now with the group that has a very high chance of having the mineral.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You're looking for a mining site, not just an asteroid that has it somewhere
Yes, it is true that 99% of asteroids have this ore, but the more important question is where on the asteroid the ore is, and in what concentration.  Consider this: Iron can be found pretty much everywhere in the Earth's crust.  The average iron content of any random rock you find is about 5%.  If you melt that rock down, you can get 5% of its mass back as iron... but mining companies don't want to invest in rocks that only give them a 5% yield on smelting.  Instead they look for what are called economically viable ores which in most regions are considered rocks containing at least 60% iron. These rocks are far more rare than you common garden variety rock, but it takes so much less energy to refine them that it is worth the added costs to find them.  Because market rates are based on the cost of 60% iron ores, a company will lose money trying to mine 5% ores because the cost to refine them is higher than what you can make back from selling them.
Now let's consider how scanning materials from a distance actually works.  The best way to tell what a thing is made out of is to vaporize a chunk of it, and to pass a light through the vapor to see where the EM spectral banding occurs.  This will tell you both what, and how much of each element is present in a sample. You can only do spectrometry on vaporized materials which means you can not scan a whole asteroid, just the tiny little pricks you choose to vaporize for analysis.  This can be done with either a high powered laser or impactor probe.  Either way, you'll have a limited number of "scans" you can do before your run out of probes or power reserves for the laser.  So when you "scan" an asteroid, you are blasting little holes in it to scan the vapor clouds to see not just if there is the ore you are looking for, but how economically viable the concentration is.
Let's say for example you are looking for platinum (though any rare Earth element would work for this answer)  An asteroid may have 1000 grams per ton in one spot, and then a few meters over it might be 1 gram per ton.  So, to scan an asteroid, you will fire blindly at a few random places to see if any show good concentrations of ore.  Your false negatives are because this is a lot like playing a game of battleship.  You fire at a few random spots, and you may or may not hit what you are looking for.  The reason it has a good positive rate is because once you find a good pocket of ore, you can start focusing more blasts in that area to better determine the size and overall density of the ore pocket you found.  So you might only commit 1 shots per square kilometer of asteroid to look for ore pockets, but once you find one, you might commit dozens if not 100s of shots to mapping it out in detail to make sure the vein is both large and rich enough to be profitable.

The Conspiracy
There are a few ways this could go wrong for your shifty scanner tech.  One way is to over-commit to a sub-par ore deposit.  Maybe he found an almost viable vien, and then wasted all of his remaining scans to over mapping the area to try to "prove" a non-viable mining site's merit.
Another way it could go wrong would be if he spends up all of his blind shots on this single asteroid believing he will eventually hit pay dirt. Protocol may dictate that you scan dozens of asteroids on your approach but your tech instead decides to focus all of his scans on the asteroid he has a reason to go to.  99% of the time, this will eventually yield an economically viable vien, but if the asteroid you target came from a different source than the rest of the cluster, there may simply be no ore on it.
Either way, the problem is an issue of overcommitting his scans on a poor target.  So, if he has enough time and/or resources to do 1000 scans on his approach, and wastes them all on this one bad region, then they will all come up negative, by the time he realizes that this is more than just bad luck, he will no longer have enough scans left to widen his search area and will definitely not have enough scans left to properly map out a good hit, even if he gets one.
Another way it could go wrong is if your tech gets a positive scan and then decides not to map the vein.  After all, everyone knows if you get lucky enough to get a positive scan, it's almost always large enough of a vein to be worth going after, but this could be a fringe case where the scanner tech just got really "lucky" to be able to exactly hit a tiny vein of ore, but when they get there with equipment designed to process  thousands of tons of rock, they may find the whole vien was only a tiny bit of rock and everything around it is economically unviable.

Good explanation of the reason for a manual scan. There is a different method for the scan. Instead of grabbing or drilling holes for samples to scan, you could use a different method. Namely ground penetrating radar. Using sound, GPR, or another type of seismic wave you could scan a material based on the echo's of the vibrations. GPR is used in the Perseverance on Mars. It can't scan that deep however (~10m), and would require you to be on the surface for a manual scan. But can make scans as you move it.

@vinzzz001 GPR tells you the subsurface geometry of an area by detecting for areas of high and low radar reflectiveness, but it does not do a good job of showing what subsurface things are made out of.  You can generally tell how metallic a rock is, but would not be able to distinguish one ore from another, especially if looking for trace elements (which will be any metal worth going to space for).

One can also use a small kinetic impactor to kick up a debris cloud and fly the probe through the dust to sample the particulate matter.   This has a similar situation of "well there wasn't any of the ore in this region, so none was detected" as the laser sampling.
Maybe it is cheaper to have a probe that does a bunch of asteroid fly-bys on a single mission, using a "cannon" to blast away ejecta for sampling, and identify candidates for lander missions, than to send satellites that would more thoroughly search each asteroid.

Are you calling me a common garden variety rock?!

If you go with Uranium-238 or thorium-232 rich asteroids, you could scan their presence through detection of radon-222, which is produced along the decay chain of those elements.
Radon being a gas and being emitted in whiffs, it can be easily missed by detectors placed in the wrong direction with respect to the whiff emitted in the vacuum of space.

An issue with this answer is that both of those decay chains release gamma rays.
A gamma detector would almost certainly detect asteroids with large quantities of either element.  Their decay chains would be constantly kicking off high energy photons that can pass through fairly significant amounts of matter.
What is worse is that specific decays have identifiable energies, so you can tell exactly what elements are decaying from the spectrum data.
You try to could hand wave this by saying sometimes the elements are exclusively deep in the core, blocking enough gamma rays.

Asteroids are not all homogenous. Many are fragile balls of dirt in frozen slush. Others are a mix of rocks in a cake of dust.
So have your ship scan the asteroid surface with something like spectography, perhaps aided by a laser to vaporize material for easier scans. There is some likelihood that in a given slushball or cake, none of the desired material is on the surface, while there is plenty inside. This might involve the history of the asteroid, like capturing debris from the collision between two others.

Fire a probe
The mineral is a rare isotope of a common element. The asteroids are scanned by firing a probe at the asteroid and taking a sample and doing spectroscopy on them. This is expensive, but it tells you if the element is present. The second test, to detect if the isotope fails, often fails, but so long as the element is present the isotope will always be somewhere on the asteroid.
The navigator says he fires the probe, actually fires a cheap decoy, pockets the cash, and flies the ship to the asteroid with their personal interest. Moving their spaceship costs a lot more than a probe, and when they get there they find there is none of the common element there and so the rare isotope can't be there. They are now liable for the cost of moving the spaceship.

On the topic of Scanner-Logic
A key point in your question (although not very obvious at first glance) is the fact that you actually need two minerals or mineral-states. Like you mentioned with Cadmium and Cadmium-oxide.
I take this as:
There is a mineral, let's name it M, which is what the mining company is after. But M occurs with M+MX almost all the time. Which is a good thing for this guy (the navigator) who actually wants that MX and "generously" leaves the M to the company. But then there is this one special case, where he "thinks" he aims for the next M+MX asteroid, but it turns out only MX is present, M is missing, the company is mad and the guy is busted.
The scanner used by the company is officially supposed to detect M but is actually capable of detecting M+MX (which is either known or not known to the company and the guy; probably not known to both of them to make sense). Because of the technology used (maybe a built-in defect by accident or by sabotage or by secretly added feature) and the nature of MX, the scanner actually scans MX most of the time.
The scanner is good at detecting M+MX (because MX is present) but cannot discern very well if only one of them is present in an asteroid. MX (both, alone or in conjunction as M+MX has a somewhat stronger signal or chance of detection. M alone is mostly (to always) missed by the scanner - which effectively means, the scanner is not capable of what it was built for (detecting M).
Sidenote: In the table below this would be the third row, so the scanner not being able to scan M well, can be changed to allow reliably detecting M as well.
So it can happen that the scanner beeps a "found it!"-signal although he has found only MX (that is the special case, where the guy gets busted).
Let's see:
 Asteroid        Scanner               Result                 
hasM  hasMX    scans  beeps    company(M)   navigator(MX)
  Y    Y         MX     Y        happy         happy
  N    N         -      N         ...           ...         (just keep searching)      
  Y    N        (M)    (N)      (happy)      (not happy)    (but doesn't matter)            
  N    Y         MX     Y      not happy       (happy)      (but busted, so actually not that happy)

The third row is open to adjustments. If needed, the scanner result for M alone can be anything from 0%-100% accuracy. I assumed a very low accuracy in this case, as described. If needed, the scanner can "beep". The result stays the same, the company would be happy because they found M, and the guy may or may not be happy, depending on his expectations. Either he expects MX to be there but is surprised/disappointed, or he knows that MX is not there and just lets the company do its thing (although this knowledge about the "MX is not there"-fact cannot be obtained by this same scanner, as it cannot pickup any traces of MX obviously).
Mutual exclusive interests and "indirect" detection variants: A possible explanation can be, that the interests of the guy and the company are mutually exclusive. Meaning that M is deemed the valuable substance and MX is considered as worthless by the company but the guy sees this differently. He is interested either only in MX or also thinks M+MX is acceptable, probably the latter, because the mission has to satisfy both the needs of the company and the guy to be launched. The thing is: The company cannot detect M directly. For some reason this is not possible (because of properties of M or other physics effects or knowledge or by hardware constraints or whatever). But the R&D-division manages to build an MX-detector - which is the worthless substance, but because it is known to occur "only" as M+MX that is good enough for the company. Problem is, they are not aware that this is not the "only" way it can occur. MX can occur in pure form also. This is the special case were things-hit-the-fan for the guy. But why the company's scientists are not aware of this form needs to be explained somehow, maybe it is just carelessness or the discovery of this case comes in too late / or it is discovered (maybe tragically) exactly through this mission and probably the people on the mission are going to get hurt).
So in the end, there really are various solutions for this story lineup. But you need this special scanner which detects something that the scanner isn't supposed to scan (or is explained by indirect detection). Which in turn needs a special mineral/state configuration.
In the case I presented, this "defect" is turned into a "feature"... the scanner can detect "more" instead of "less".
This is were the contradiction would come in with only one mineral: If the scanner has the capability of scanning only "the" mineral, it can only "beep" if the mineral is "present". It cannot "not detect" the mineral but also "beep" - unless there is some kind of defect in the scanner (or the guy, for that matter).
Sidenote: You might want to check out my answer "The Avoidance-Detector" to have another take of explanation.
Conclusion
Now the only thing you have to do is find suitable names for M and MX. What kind of material or substance or isotope or whatever they are is free to chose I guess. To be plausible you need to either say the MX-effect is not that abundant as the M+MX combination, or you can tweak the sensitivity of the scanner as described being more attuned to the MX and M+MX than the M deposits.
Since I put a lot of effort in this (it was a fun challenge in the end, though and I hope I got everything right), I may suggest naming one of the minerals "Antarium" :D But it is your decision if you want that to happen.
I think this can make a really good suspense story with a surprise twist. Have fun writing it! Let me know when you finish it :)

@mousetail: I wonder if I really provide a solution or rather just have reverse-engineered your story setup to your starting-point you already developed with a similar logic-table ;)

It is not uncommon in science to look for a detectable coorilary when you don't know how to look for the primary fact, like how immunologists detect for antibodies when looking for a virus that they can't detect.  So if you mix this idea with L.Dutches answer, maybe you can detect the Radon that gasses out out of an asteroid, but not the the deeply buried Uranium; so, you know you may in fact be chasing Radon, not Uranium, but sometimes a pocket of Radon is just a pocket of Radon.

Super tiny traces of the mineral.
Edit/Discalimer: I kind of missed the conspiracy aspect of the story and was focused more on explaining the false-negative characteristic of the mineral... my proposals might not be a good fit for your story in this case. Maybe you want to emphasize the last paragraph in your question more to be considered.

The first thing coming to mind is of course like you want to do mineral-mining big time. But this would not make it necessary to scan for it. If 99% of asteroids are supposed to carry this mineral and this quote is known to the mining company, then just hit on the next rock you find...
BUT. If the mineral you need to mine is only available in tiny traces, say only a few atoms per asteroid or maybe a few grams, this can still mean 99% of them having that mineral, but even if you dig into it, you are only so-and-so likely to really find this trace.
This also is  the reason why scanners are 100% correct IF they detect those traces (because they are located beneficially near the surface), but will miss a high amount of it, because the scanners cannot penetrate the surfaces too much.
The scanner could be anything from neutrino-detectors to gravitational-anomaly-detectors or whatever.
Alternatively: The mineral could be very unstable. Even if the scanner says, it is there and it also is, if you dig it up, it could dissolve when treated wrong (too much heat, too much vibration, too much light or other radiation, ...) and all the effort was in vain.
This not exactly a high rate of false-negatives while scanning, but the effect would be the same, meaning: you can scan it (easily), it is possible to obtain it (maybe difficult), but not in the high rates as the abundance-quota tells you (you will not gain all the 99% that exist in all the asteroids).
Suggestion for the mineral: It could be an anti-matter-nucleus.
The (fictional) theory says, that in the formation of asteroids (any or only some) types enclosed an anti-matter particle, which was stabilized because of "some" physical effect (enter a decent amount of tech-babbel here). It can be detected, because asteroids tend to "wobble" in a certain way and also have a dislocated barycenter when observing their rotations. But if you try to dig into the asteroid, the stabilizing effect might vanish too early, the anti-matter particle annihilates and explodes.
Therefore, Mining is dangerous, but also very lucrative, because anti-matter is needed for ship propulsion. To do it "right" you need to act very slowly and have a electro-magnetic shielding in place around the mining drill, which is able to stabilize the anti-matter particle until it can be stored for longer in some suitable container.
Suggestion 2: The periodic table has some 100 elements listed. But there can be more. Problem is, they are so unstable, they do not exist for long in our universe (up to this point, this is even real. I think there are 103 elements, but artificially generated can be up to 117 or so). But maybe they exist long enough in some special asteroids. Maybe they even only exist in some special solar-system or asteroid belt somewhere. With arbitrarily dangerous circumstances, as your story needs to have, like common sun-bursts, high radiation, instable gas clouds ready to explode when ignited by thrusters, and so on.
The name is kinda ridiculous for native speakers, but check this out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darmstadtium

The Avoidance-Detector
See my answer about Scanner-Logic to understand this section here:
A take on the "not-there"-detector: The interests of the company have to be to avoid the mineral M because of some dangerous properties. They manage to build an appropriate scanner to detect the presence of M but invert its output to beep (or light up "green") only if (or rather: as long as) M was not found. Showing something like "all safe, go ahead".
Now the interests of the guy need to be incorporated: Only if the scanner is defective or in-accurate to some degree and also detects M+MX but still shows "all good". Then the guy can say (or assume) "okay, we can go there" but when they mine, the-trying-to-be-avoided-situation M happens. The blame could be on the guy (if he is not trustworthy), if he was manipulating the scanner (or as you said, bluntly ignoring it, making him being (grossly) negligent on purpose/"with intent" (or without), in fact the culprit/a criminal). But it is also likely that the blame falls on the scanner for being unreliable, if the company trusts the guy.
The configuration of the minerals need be: The company needs to avoid finding M, actually searching for something different, a mineral MX in which the guy also has or has no interest. The property of M and MX have to be, that they cancel each other out for the scanning-process. The consequence is, the scanner still shows the absence of M and lits "green, all good", despite M being there actually, but the presence is concealed because of MX - this would be the state M+MX.
There might (or might not) be a second scanner which is capable of detecting MX to any accuracy needed for the story. This would be beneficial for the company. But this would need the property that the scanner can detect MX alone and can also detect M+MX, so that the special situation for the guy can take place. But, this makes the scanner actually capable of detecting the concealed form... This could be some supernatural side-effect maybe or a really plot-convenient, unintended coincidence (this would make some kind of Quantum-Scanner an ideal candidate, because of the inherently associated "uncertainty"). The concealed state should be not even known by anyone. But how to convey that to the reader to be plausible then, might be difficult.
So maybe there is no second scanner for the MX-presence. The company can only try to make sure, that M is avoided and relies on the estimated abundance (or at least hoped-for-abundance) of MX being in nearly any asteroid to be encountered at that particular asteroid-belt.
In case of a possible sampling-mission: The (estimated) quota could be deduced from something like a sample, where MX alone was found. Maybe from a stray asteroid swarm impacting somewhere closer or some deep-space asteroid-probing-mission by drones. Then some science is taking place and it is postulated that there has to be much more of that mineral, but drones won't cut the delicate mission requirements. Humans have to be sent... which leads into disaster for the guy.
In this probing-scenario, also M should be encountered, to make clear that this is to be avoided in future mining missions (maybe some drones were lost due to this). After some efforts, a detector for the presence of M can be built and used as the avoidance-detector. But MX for some reason is undetectable (with the current hardware). Also, to be plausible, the concealed state M+MX has to remain undiscovered (despite both minerals probably being found during the same mission or even in the same stray asteroid? Maybe there need to be separate asteroids for each type, so the M+MX case remains unknown until the first encounter by the human mission.
Results: This would also add the plausible outcome for the guy that this was all just a case of "really bad luck", because nobody could foresee the existence of M+MX (meaning this is the first encounter with M+MX) or at least the presence of M+MX on that asteroid (it "slipped through the detector", bad luck or bad scanner hardware, or unreliable guy and deemed guilty when not trusted by the company).
